# Using a modal as template to edit/delete

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

I have some rows shown in a table (each one is a row of the related model database table). For each row I show a button that shows a modal asking for confirmation to delete it.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSquD.png][1]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGhSO.png][2]

The modal code is a blade template.

For a table with a single row, i have no problem. I can pass the id as variable to the modal. But i dont know how to send the selected one (logically, its including the modal with the last value of the $subnet var).

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

```
...
@foreach($subnets as $subnet)
<tr>
  <td>{{$subnet->name}}</td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary">Edit</button><button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteSubnet">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@include('inc.modals.modal_deleteSubnet',['subnet' => $subnet])
...





<div class="modal fade" id="deleteSubnet" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteSubnetLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteSubnetLabel">Delete subnet</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="/subnets/{{$subnet->id}}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this subnet ({{$subnet->name}})?<p>                          
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Delete">
                </span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSquD.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGhSO.png
```

Comment: could you please explain bit more

Comment: Sorry for the explanation.

Comment: You can add action to when press the button open the modal with your selected id.

Comment: the problem is I cant understand this clearly. So  to provide a better answer its better if you could explain bit more

Comment: Yeah, Nipun. Im trying. Sorry. Hope the images I've added help understanding the problem.

Comment: The code shows the part of the code in which the table is presented with the related delete button.
And also the code of the modal blade.

Comment: The modal must be dynamic depeding on the button that has been pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna check [this section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) on Bootstrap's website.

In your case this could be translated to:

1. Add `data-id="{{ $subnet->id }}"` to your button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary">Edit</button><button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteSubnet" data-id="{{ $subnet->id }}">Delete</button>
```

2. Add this jQuery snippet.

```
$('#deleteSubnet').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
      var id = button.data('id')
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('form').attr('action', '/subnets/' + id)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your form add a bind id

```html
@foreach($subnets as $subnet)
<tr>
  <td>{{$subnet->name}}</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary" data-id="{{$subnet->id}}">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary" data-id="{{$subnet->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteSubnet">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Add a "id" in your form to get in jquery. `<form method="POST id="formId">`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // you can add a better validation to button like a ID or class
    $("button").each(function () {
        $(this).onClick(function () {
            var action = "/subnets/" + $(this).data().id;
            $("#formId").attr("action", action);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and for more fields like the subnet->name?

Comment: There are two ways to do this: passing the whole object to jquery, or searching the database again (which in large tables is more feasible due to less data consumption on the screen.)

Answer (score 0):

Without any javascript workarounds:

```
<button ...  data-target="#deleteSubnet-{{ $subnet->id }}">Delete</button>
         ....

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteSubnet-{{ $subnet->id }}" ... >
         ....
</div>
```

Should work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AddEditModal" role="dialog" ng-show="showEditModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button" ng-click="loadDetails()">
                    ×
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" ng-show="newType">Employee - New</h4>
                <h4 class="modal-title" ng-hide="newType">Employee - Edit</h4>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" name="employeeForm" ng-submit="saveEmployee(detail,employeeForm.$valid)">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        <div ng-repeat="error in errors">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">× </button>
                                <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                                {{error}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : employeeForm.EmpCode.$invalid && !employeeForm.EmpCode.$pristine }">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="EmpCode"><b>Employee Code:</b> </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="EmpCode" ng-model="detail.EmpCode" required>
                                <p ng-show="employeeForm.EmpCode.$invalid && !employeeForm.EmpCode.$pristine" class="help-block">Employee is required.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : employeeForm.FirstName.$invalid && !employeeForm.FirstName.$pristine }">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="FirstName"><b>First Name :</b> </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="FirstName" ng-model="detail.FirstName" required>
                                <p ng-show="employeeForm.FirstName.$invalid && !employeeForm.FirstName.$pristine" class="help-block">First Name is required.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : employeeForm.LastName.$invalid && !employeeForm.LastName.$pristine }">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="LastName"><b>Last Name :</b> </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="LastName" ng-model="detail.LastName" required>
                                <p ng-show="employeeForm.LastName.$invalid && !employeeForm.LastName.$pristine" class="help-block">Last Name is required.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-show="newType" ng-disabled="employeeForm.$invalid">
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                        Save
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-hide="newType" ng-disabled="employeeForm.$invalid">
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                        Save Changes
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="removeFormDetails()"><i class="fa clip-close-3"></i>Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Delete Section-->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" role="dialog" ng-show="showDeleteModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you really want to delete this User?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-bricky" type="button" ng-click="deleteEmployee(detail)">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    Delete
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-green" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" ng-click="removeFormDetails()">
                    <i class="fa clip-close-3"></i>
                    Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```